# How to stop setInterval defined outside the useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a progress bar which increase it's value in every 5 seconds. I used setInterval which increase the state value and trying to clearInterval once state value is 100. But it's not clearing the interval and state value is not getting changed properly.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [percentage,setPercentage] = useState(99)

  let progressInterval = setInterval(()=>{
    console.log(percentage);
    setPercentage(percentage+1);
  },10000);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(percentage === 100) {
      console.log("completed");
      clearInterval(progressInterval);
    }
  }, [percentage])

  const progress = {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    width: `${percentage}%`,
    textAlign: 'right',
  }
  const fullWidth = {
    border: '1px solid black',
    backgroundColor: '#eff',
    margin: '10px'
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div style={fullWidth}>
        <div style={progress}>{percentage}%</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the state your component will be rerender and your `progressInterval` variable will be reinitialize.

you should initizalize the variable of interval inside a callback function:

```
import {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';

let progressInterval = '';
function App() {
  const [percentage,setPercentage] = useState(99);
  const initInterval = useCallback(() => {
    progressInterval = setInterval(()=>{
      console.log(percentage);
      setPercentage(percentage+1);
    },10000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(percentage === 100) {
      console.log("completed");
      clearInterval(progressInterval);
    }
  }, [percentage])
  const progress = {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    width: `${percentage}%`,
    textAlign: 'right',
  }
  const fullWidth = {
    border: '1px solid black',
    backgroundColor: '#eff',
    margin: '10px'
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div style={fullWidth}>
        <div style={progress}>{percentage}%</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

export default App;

Comment: It's not increasing the value of the state by 1
Value is increase like 1,6,23,76,237 and on and on

Answer (score 0):

If `progressInterval` can be a state variable, this might be the solution:

```
function App() {
  const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(99);
  const [progressInterval, setProgressInterval] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let progressInterval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(percentage);
      setPercentage((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 10000);

    setProgressInterval(progressInterval);

    // Optional but a recommendation
    // Clearing the interval if component unmounts before reaching 100 percent
    return () => clearInterval(progressInterval);

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (percentage === 100) {
      console.log("completed");
      clearInterval(progressInterval);
    }
  }, [percentage]);

... rest of the code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a return function to your useEffect like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
                const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    
                  if(progress < 0.9){
                    setProgress(progress + 0.2);
                  }
                  else{
                    retrieveData();
                  }
    
                }, 1000);
                return () => {
                  clearTimeout(timer);
                };
              }, [progress]);
```